# Is good practice to store data in service angular 2

Tags: angular, service

In a lot of tutorials, some data (e.g. list of todos) is stored in service. Is it good practice? I'm new in Angular 2 and I want to learn how code right.

Some code example:

```
@Injectable()
export class JsonRestService {

    jsonObject = {};
    jsonContent = {};

    constructor(private http:Http) {
        this.getXmlInJson()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.startGeneratingHtmlTemplateProcess(data),
            error => console.log(error + " - Błąd pobrania jsona")
        );
    }

    getXmlInJson() {
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/xml";
        return this.http.get(url);
    }

    public convertRestJsonToObject$() {
        this.getXmlInJson()
        .subscribe(
            data =>  this.startGeneratingHtmlTemplateProcess(data.json),
            error => console.log(error + " - Błąd pobrania jsona")
        );
   }

   private startGeneratingHtmlTemplateProcess(data) {
        this.jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body);
        this.jsonContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data._body));
        console.log(this.jsonObject);
        console.log("Json:");
        console.log(this.jsonContent);
   }

   showObjectInConsole() {
       console.log("Wyzwolone prze przycisk: ");
       console.log(this.jsonObject);
   }

}
```

Comment: if you need to store data you can use redux.

Comment: In general, store as little as possible. If you do need to store data, it will likely stem from an optimization (e.g. caching) but try to avoid it as much as possible. In this case, the code looks fishy, with the double `JSON.parse` anyway. I would not store such data. Even if you need to improve startup time by removing a round trip to fetch templates, put them in a JSON file and that way your service will remain transparent and easy to test.

Answer (score 6):

While services are often used to retrieve/update data by interacting with a data source, they can be quite handy in storing data as well. For example, if you need to retrieve a large piece of data, you can cache it in the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{

    mydata: Array<string>[];

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    loadData(): Observable<string[]> {
        if (this.mydata){
            return Observable.from(this.mydata);  // return from cache
        } else
        {
            return this.http.get("./assets/LargeDataSet.json")
                .map(res => res.json())
                .do(data => this.mydata = data);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the retrieval of a large data set will happen on the first call of loadData(), while the subsequent calls will return the data fast without making a time-consuming http.get(). Since a service can be a singleton, many components can take an advantage of using the data cached in the service.
You can also store an app state inside a singleton service.

Comment: Why are you creating an observable to return; Why not just return the mydata value?

Comment: @FlyingV This method returns an observable in both cases: 1. cache exists 2. no cached value. This uniformed return type allows components to invoke loadData().subscribe() without thinking if the data was cached or is arriving from the server.

Comment: I tried to so a similar thing, but in my case the 'mydata' variable is 'undefined' on page refresh. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The good practice is to use services to provide datas. 
A service is a class with method that call the api (or whatever) to get (or post, or put or delete) the data and return the result to the component.